# What is downshard in prometheus?

Tags: prometheus

In prometheus log file，I found the following message:

> ts=2023-06-24T14:52:39.309Z caller=dedupe.go:112 component=remote
> level=debug remote_name=3c6b08 url=https://example.com/api/v1/prom
> msg="Not downsharding due to being too far behind"

what is downshard in prometheus remote write and when need to downshard?